# Holder of German National Visa (Type D). Can my first point of entry be through Switzerland?

Tags: schengen, germany

We are moving to Germany on a long-stay national visa (Type D). The easiest route would be to land in Basel, Switzerland, where someone would pick us up from there.

Are there any restrictions which would require the first country of entry to be Germany and not Switzerland?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enter the Schengen Area via any Schengen country, so France or Switzerland are fine. During the validity of your D visa you can also at any time spend up to 90 days out of 180 in other Schengen countries.

Note that BSL (the Basel-Mulhouse-Freiburg Euro-Airport) is actually in France. There are French and Swiss sides of the airport, but when arriving from a non-EU country you can pick which side you exit to (since both Switzerland and France are now in Schengen this only changes things for customs purposes, but it probably makes more sense to exit on the French side if you are going to Germany).

Note also that we have had a few reports that some Turkish Airlines agents in IST incorrectly think that you need to fly directly to the country which issued the visa. This may occasionally occur elsewhere. This is not correct, and you should (politely but firmly) insist that they check on their terminal or call a supervisor if they tell you so.

Comment: Do make sure to be at the correct sector for whoever picks you up. Ask them what is easiest for them (French or Swiss sector) and then take the exit accordingly.